# Troubleshooting AD LDS

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

I have a Win 2012 Server that I've created a new AD LDS forest on. I'm running a software application on the server that uses this forest for user credentials. The software application is not logging me in. I've used `dsquery` to pull the forest objects from the DN with:

`dsquery * -s 192.168.1.2 "DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com"`

This is successful.

However, using `ldapsearch` it is another story:

```
ldapsearch -h 192.168.1.2 -p 389 "DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com"

ldap_search: Operations error
ldap_search: additional info: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090724, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v23f0
```

Question:

- Why does `dsquery` work and `ldapsearch` does not?
- Any ideas on the `ldapsearch` error?

---

**EDIT:**

In response to @longneck I tried the following (with associated result):

```
ldapsearch -v -d 4 -h 192.168.1.2 -p 389 -w <PASSWORD> -D '<DOMAIN>\Administrator' "DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com"

ldap_open( 192.168.1.2, 389 )ldapsearch -h 192.168.1.2 -p 389 "DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com"
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials
ldap_bind: additional info: 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 2030, v23f0
```

I was not sure about the `-D` flag at all since the help states that `-D` is `bind dn` which to me is DN, but as you can see from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13039327/808946) the help for that param is not intuitive.

I can say for certain that the password I've supplied above with the `-w` flag is correct so I'm not sure why the command is failing.

Comment: `'<DOMAIN>\Administrator'` is not a DN. `CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=trenam,DC=com` is. You need to find the distinguished name (DN) of the user you want to authenticate (bind) as and specify that. I'm not familiar with the tools that LDS provides, but with AD DS in the MMC, there's a menu option to turn on called "Advanced Features" which adds the "Attribute Editor" tab on user objects, and you can see the DN there.

Answer (score 2):

`dsquery` uses the credentials of the logged in user to authenticate (bind) to the directory. `ldapsearch` does not. Look at the `-D` and the `-W/w` options for `ldapsearch`.

Comment: Please see the edit I've made in response to you.